# Problem involving the algebraic orders of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> **Problem:** If $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ have the algebraic orders $h$ and $k$ at $z=a$, show that
>
> **(a)** $fg$ has the order $h+k$
>
> **(b)** $f/g$ the order $h-k$
>
> **(c)** $f+g$ an order which does not exceed $\max\ (h,k)$.

**Question:** I'm not sure how to approach (c), and feel that my proof for (b) has a dubious step in it that I highlighted below.

**Attempt for (a):**

1. To say that $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ have algebraic orders $h$ and $k$ respectively at $z = a$ is to say that

   $$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} |(z-a)|^{\alpha} |f(z)| = 0 \text{ for all } \alpha > r
   $$

   and

   $$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} |(z-a)|^{\beta} |g(z)| = 0 \text{ for all } \beta > k
   $$

   where $h$ and $k$ are the **minimal integers** satisfying these properties.
2. Then we have that

   \begin{align*}
   & \lim_{n \to \infty} |(z-a)|^{\alpha+\beta} |f(z) \cdot g(z)| = 0 \\
   \iff & \lim_{n \to \infty} |(z-a)|^{\alpha} |(z-a)|^{\beta} |f(z) \cdot g(z)| = 0\\
    \iff & \alpha + \beta > h + k \\
   \end{align*}

   as desired.

**Attempt for (b):**

1. First, we observe that if $g(z) \ne 0$, then

   \begin{align*}
   & \lim_{n \to \infty}  |(z-a)|^{\beta} \left|g(z)\right| = 0 \\
   \iff & \underbrace{\lim_{n \to \infty} |(z-a)|^{-\beta} \left|{1 \over g(z)}\right| = 0 }_{\text{this feels dubious to me}}\\
    \iff & - \beta > - k \\
   \end{align*}
2. Then if we continue to assume that $g(z) \ne 0$, we have that

   \begin{align*}
   & \lim_{n \to \infty} |(z-a)|^{\alpha-\beta} \left|{f(z) \over g(z)}\right| = 0 \\
   \iff & \lim_{n \to \infty} |(z-a)|^{\alpha} |(z-a)|^{-\beta} \left|{f(z) \over g(z)}\right| = 0\\
    \iff & \alpha - \beta > h - k \\
   \end{align*}

   as desired.